# How do you enable touch interaction in Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

Has anyone tried to add touch interaction to CorePlot?

I'm trying to implement custom layer to be able to draw a line on the chart which will show specific value and will draw itself in specified location when user touches chart area, but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: Hi Nick, have u got any way to do it? Im searching for the same. I need the interaction on custom layer at the top and also on graph layer. Pls post the way u got.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable interaction by changing the allowsuserinteraction property.

`[[graph defaultPlotSpace] setAllowsUserInteraction:TRUE];`

Comment: I've already set setAllowsUserInteraction:TRUE but the problem is that when I'm adding my custom layer to the chart - the chart itself stops receiving any touch events